# How to uninstall (pip) at all from cmd?

Tags: python, cmd, pip, python-imaging-library

How to uninstall  the whole pip in my cmd without leaving any pip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip uninstall pip` should be able to uninstall the whole pip without leaving pip.